# Java connect to Cassandra NoHostAvailableException

Tags: java, database, cassandra

My code in Java:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cluster cluster;
    Session session;

    cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
                .withPort(9042)
                .build();

    session = cluster.connect("Bundesliga");

    session.execute("INSERT INTO test(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5) VALUES(0,0,0,0,0)");
}
```

Error Message:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (null))    at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:196)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:80)
>     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1145)
>     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:149)  at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:225)    at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:258)    at
>   cassandra.cassandra_main.main(cassandra_main.java:19)

I have already looked in `cassandra.yaml`:

> start_native_transport: true
>
> native_transport_port: 9042

Comment: Are you sure that cassandra is listening on localhost? Since the nodes in a cassandra cluster must talk to each other they usually open their port on the external IP address.

Comment: in cassandra.yaml is the listen_adress on localhost

Comment: can you include output of `netstat -anp | grep 9042` ?

Comment: tcp    0    0  0.0.0.0:9042    0.0.0.0:0*        LISTEN      3738/java

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

The problem were, that the version of the cassandra-driver-core was not compatible with the cassandra version.